# How can I start service on start up in android? + need some other advice

Tags: android, service, battery

I'm building an app that collects info about the battery (using background service).
I want this service to start running from the moment I turn on the phone, How do I do it?

On the other hand I want to activate the GUI (interface) of the app only when the user clicks on the app. The app and the background service are in the same project.

Is this the correct way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct way to do it: see https://web.archive.org/web/20210122071943/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/07/permissions-journey-receivebootcomplete.html for info about listening for the BOOT_COMPLETED Intent. You can start your Service in the BroadcastReceiver and then bind to it in your Activity.

Comment: I bind it in OnCreate() function of the activity.
In other words when I start the activity.

Comment: Their is one thing that I didn't understand, Do I need to create this BatteryReceiver? Don't I need to register it?
How can I tell my app/project that this class is first to run (I use eclipse)?

Comment: For testing in Eclipse you will need to start it manually: Eclipse requires you to have an Activity to start. I'd suggest starting an Activity that starts the Service. For production deployments the BroadcastReceiver can start the Service.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, I need to create another activity that uses the extended BroadcastReceiver that I created to lunch my service, Is it correct?

Comment: The BOOT_COMPLETED Intent is only sent when the phone is rebooted, so it can not really be debugged. You need to create the BroadcastReceiver to start the Service when the app is deployed, but for debugging you will need an Activity that starts the Service (in `onCreate` or `onResume`).

Comment: OK. I don't understand where do I need to the BroadcastReceiver to start the Service when the app is deployed?
The part of debugging I understand.

Comment: If you want the service to be Automatically started when the phone is rebooted then you will need the BroadcastReceiver to be setup and the appropriate definitions in the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @Femi let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1057/discussion-between-alex-kapustian-and-femi)